# When a User is hitting the Admin dashborad url then how can i redirect into the own url

Tags: angular

when i am trying soo many times ,
when a user is hitting the admin dashborad url to redirect into the own page but it not working
i have a Role like " SuperAdmin,CompanyAdmin,UserAdmin,Opertation"

app.routing.ts file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/admin/user-vehicles",
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "auth/login",
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "auth/reset-password",
    component: ResetPasswordComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "registration",
    component: RegistrationComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "forgotpassword",
    component: ForgetPasswordComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "",
    component: ContentLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    children: content,
  },
  {
    path: "",
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    children: full,
  },

  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "",
  },
];
```

admin.guard.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
  CanDeactivate,
} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "../services/firebase/auth.service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // Guard for userRole is login or not
    // var Role=localStorage.getItem('UserRole')
    let user = localStorage.getItem("Id");
    if (!user) {
      this.router.navigate(["/auth/login"]);
      return true;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic like in your **app.component.ts**

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
    
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
      ) {
        this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
          if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    
            const user = localStorage.getItem("Id");
            const Role = localStorage.getItem('UserRole')
            if (user && Role && Role === 'User' && ev.url.includes('/admin)) {
                this.router.navigate(['user/home']);
          }
        }
      }
```

> Similary for your all roles you can define if condition and can
> redirect on their main route let's if user then user's default page,
> if super admin then it might be **superAdmin/dashboard** anything like
> this.

**Second way:**

Another way to achieve this is to use [ngx-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions) using which you can control your route based on role.

attaching [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-permission-demo-qrji88) demo for more clarification.

[Official doc](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions#readme)

[NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions)